# audiotrack class in windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

i am currently working on a audio streaming app for windows desktop 8.1, i cant seem to figure out how to use the audiotrack class it works fine in windows phone, infact i have a working windows phone app using this code the only problem with it seems to be the audiotrack class is only for windows phone

```
public class Album : INotifyPropertyChanged

  {

    public Album(string ID,string Albumname,string ImageURL,bool free, List<AudioTrack> Playlist)
    {
        ProductId = ID;
        this.AlbumName = Albumname;
        PlayList = Playlist;
        _imagepath = ImageURL;
        Free = free;
    }
    public string ProductId;
    public List<AudioTrack> PlayList;
    public string AlbumName {get;set;}
    public string AlbumTitle
```

this is some of my code, could anyone help alter this so it works in windows 8.1 ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All you had shown in your code is the Data Structure, that doesn't convey what you had tried till now.  Can you post your query as what you need to achieve - and what you tried till now?

BTW, Windows Phone 8.1/ Windows 8.1 has Media Element control that allows you to play Audio in your application(even in background).